# Microsoft Excel formula to sum some data if they meet the requirement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to get the sum of profit for each specific month. the only possible way i think right now is to check if the month is match, example

if I need January details, the formula can sum all item profit that sold in January.

[image: Here is the Image]

Comment: Depending on what you want for output, you could use a `Pivot Table`; `SUMIFS`; use a Filter and the `SUBTOTAL` function. Many possible solutions.

Comment: One word: PivotTable

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- For Helper Data formula in cell O2:

  `=TEXT(L2,"MMMM")`
- Formula in cell R2, gets Month's Total.

  ```
  =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($O$2:$O$10=$Q2)*($M$2:$M$10))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(--($O$2:$O$10=$Q2)*($M$2:$M$10)))
  ```

**N.B.**

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed*
- *Later on you may hide Helper Data column*